# Install4j add on update installer within main installer

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to bundle an add on update installer within a main installer and detect if there is a previous version present on the machine = run the add on update installer else run the main installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would make a lot of sense to bundle a separate update installer. Also, an add-on installer cannot perform an update since it cannot change the installed version.

Installers know if they are performing an update or not and you can change their behavior based on that condition.

For example, in order to not execute a particular action for an update, set its condition expression to

```
!context.isUpdateInstallation()
```

If you have complex update-dependent logic for file installations, you can handle that in the "File filter" property of the "Install files" action.